# Function for changing text button changes back when clicking the same button again

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

As the title says, if I click on both buttons, they change from "Add" to "Update", but they change back if I click on the exact same button.

My intention is if click the edit button coming from "Add" then the targeted other button switches from Add to Update, and it needs to stay on "Update" if I click it again.

**Add Button and Function:**

```
  <button id="createNewCategory" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#categoryModal"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle " aria-hidden="true"></i> New Category</button>

  $(document).on('click', '#createNewCategory', function(){
    $("#save_button_span").html($("#save_button_span").html() === " Update" ? " Add" : " Update");
});
```

**Update Button and Function:**

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="save_button_span"> Add</span></button>

  $(document).on('click','.edit_group',function () {
            $("#save_button_span").html($("#save_button_span").html() === " Add" ? " Update" : " Add");

});
```

What do I change in both of my conditions to solve my issue?

```
$("#save_button_span").html($("#save_button_span").html() === " Update" ? " Add" : " Update");
```

Screenshot, I am clicking on "New Category" on both occasions, the button needs to stay as "Add" if I do this.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Are you sure you need those ternary statements? If I understand correctly, the logic should be: click on "New Category" `->` set text to "Add"; click on "Edit" `->` set text to "Update".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing things way too complicated. You are using logic that you don't even need. Just changed your code to this:

**Add Button and Function:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="save_button_span"> Add</span></button>

$(document).on('click','.edit_group',function () {
            $("#save_button_span").text('Add');

});
```

**Update Button and Function:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="save_button_span"> Add</span></button>

$(document).on('click','.edit_group',function () {
            $("#save_button_span").text('Update');

});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick fix, was too focus on the if condition

Comment: You're welcome :)